# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'adapterCreator')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am attempting to make a music bot for my discord server. When I run the code, the bot joins my call however it instantly stops the code and it executes the "An error occurred trying to connect."

It says in the console:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'adapterCreator')
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
Process exited with code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjqa.png)

The only part of code where 'adapterCreator' comes from is here:

```
if (command === 'play'){
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('Please provide the second argument!');
    let song = {};
    joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    })
```

The code that defines message:

*This is all under `async execute(message, args, command, client, Discord){}` in the play.js folder*

```
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a channel to run this command!')
const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the permissions to do this!');
if(!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the permissions to do this!');
const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
```

In main.js Command Handler:

```
   else if (command === 'play'){
       client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args, command);

   }
```

EDIT #2:
Showing intents:

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, Collection } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '-'

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Collection();
const command = require('./command')

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: You have to show your code for `joinVoiceChannel` and the code that defines `message` please

Comment: That's all I have for joinVoiceChannel

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same way you did it in your code and it worked just fine and I can't reproduce the crash.
So the problem might not be the code.

Have you tried to update the packages ? (`npm update`)

You have a DeprecationWarning for the on message event. This won't fix the problem but it would be good to change it to **messageCreate**.

Also to play music later you will need the connection when the bot joins a voice channel. Assign the result from **joinVoiceChannel** to a variable.

Comment: So do I literally type npm update in my terminal? Or do I need to go to the website?

Comment: And where do I change the message to messageCreate? There are lots aha. Do I change allll of them?

Comment: About the update - in your terminal you will need to locate to bot's directory and then execute "npm update". The event client.on("message", ...) was used in discord.js v12 and in the newer (v13) it's client.on("messageCreate", ...)  You will need to replace it everywhere you handle this event.

Comment: What did you mean when you said 'assign the result from joinVoiceChannel to a variable? Sorry!! I am very very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at the example [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-play-music-from-youtube)

Comment: Thanks. The problem now that I am getting is still 'undefined (reading 'adapterCreator').

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Could you post what intents you use for the "new Discord.Client" ?

Comment: Sure ill edit the post. It'll be there!

Comment: The intents seem to be correct. I just tried to run a quick test bot with the same code (without separating the command in a new file) and the bot joined without any problems. You can try the **joinVoiceChannel** function in the **main.js** file to see if it will crash again. If it's not that then you might need to reinstall the bot (maybe bad/outdated packages). I'm out of ideas...